# Does it matter what placement you have when you lost?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

In a competitive game, in game styles and level settings with flagpoles, if you manage to grab the flagpole after it was already grabbed (during the grace period), you lose less points. Does your placement matter in this case? Say if you got in second place, would you lose less points than if you were in third place?